# Does 'Aura of Hate' also boost the damage of nearby hostile fiends and undead attacking you?

Tags: dnd-5e, aura, antipaladin

The Oathbreaker Paladin option in the DMG has the following ability

> Starting at 7th level, the paladin, as well any fiends and undead
>   within 10 feet of the paladin, gains a bonus to melee weapon damage
>   rolls equal to the paladin's Charisma modifier (minimum of +1). A
>   creature can benefit from this feature from only one paladin at a
>   time. At 18th level, the range of this aura increases to 30 feet.

There's nothing in here about only affecting friendly targets. So an Oathbreaker fighting some undead or fiends with the rest of his party will actually make them more powerful from his/her presence?

This is assuming the player has been granted permission to play as an Oathbreaker by his/her DM.

Comment: *«assuming permission was granted»* — note that would also apply to an NPC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct.

The aura says that it affects *any* fiends or undead within the area so it affects **any** fiends or undead in the area.

If it was only meant to affect friendlies then it would specifically say so.

If the [lead developer's commentary](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/952721702458335232) is on interest to you:

> The Oathbreaker's Aura of Hate makes no mention of the fiends and
>   undead being the paladin's allies. In other words, the aura benefits a
>   fiend or an undead whether or not the creature is friendly toward the
>   paladin. #DnD

Comment: This is why it was meant to be an NPC archetype, not a Player Character.  This particular ability gives insight to that, as it was tailored for an Oathbreaker enemy that's accompanied by fiends or undead, not friendly fiends or undead...tough luck there :/

Comment: Jeremy Crawford has also confirmed this, if you want to add it to the answer: https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/952721702458335232